# KSH/Bash History for jailed SSH users

Tags: ssh, bash, chroot, ksh, history

How can I keep a history of activities for chroot'd SSH (not SFTP) users?
I've tried:

- created a .sh_history in their home with the proper permissions
- created a custom $HISTFILE in .profile and in its jailed /etc/profile
- exported HISTFILE after logging in.

This is how my Match in sshd_config is:

```
Match Group sshuser
            ChrootDirectory %h
            AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Additional Info:
This is in an AIX server and user's default shell is ksh. But I have no problem to switch it to bash if the solution requires it. 'chrooted' /etc/profile and user's ~/.profile is not being executed during chrooted login. It also goes without saying that the jailed home is Write-protected for the user, but the files I mentioned and others necessary for the History have enough perms for the user

Comment: can you give the output of `echo $HISTFILE` inside of the session?

Comment: the output is empty. it is also not in 'env' output.  (yes, I even copied the 'env' binaries)

Comment: Put something like `echo foo > /tmp/foo` into the `.profile` and see if that file ever shows up.  It doesn't look like your `.profile` is getting invoked if you set `$HISTFILE` and it isn't showing up when you `echo` or `env` it.

Comment: I did already, nothing happens. 
Does anyone have a chrooted environment for ssh users and history works across sessions? I wouldn't even think this would be a problem, but apparently it is